# Can't install locally cloned library in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, scikit-image

I have a virtual environment for a project in PyCharm in which I want to install a library that one of my coworkers edited. The library is scikit-image and he added a function to it after cloning it from github. It works fine in his computer, so he uploaded it to bitbucket and I used git to clone it to my computer. Now I want to install the edited library to my virtual environment in PyCharm, but when I write pip install -e PATH in the terminal, I got an "Obtaining PATH" message but after hours nothing has happened, not even an error message. 
I tried reinstalling Python and PyCharm but the problem persists. scikit-image is also not installed in the virtual environment.

Comment: Can you try `pip install -v -e PATH`? `-v` turns on verbose mode which might provide more information about where it is getting stuck. I'm also wondering *where* you are typing this. Are you sure it's the same Python as PyCharm is using? For this, you should check `which python` (or `where python` on Windows), then compare that against your interpreter settings on PyCharm.

Comment: Thanks! I'm typing it in the pycharm terminal and when I turned the verbose on and it got stuck here:
    Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\usuario\PycharmProjects\myscikit-image\setup.py) egg_info
 for package from file:///C:/Users/usuario/PycharmProjects/myscikit-image
    Running command python setup.py egg_info